# How to construct an array using make_unique

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, raii, stdarray

How can I use `std::make_unique` to construct a `std::array`?

In the following code `uptr2`'s declaration does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>


int main( )
{
    // compiles
    const std::unique_ptr< std::array<int, 1'000'000> > uptr1( new std::array<int, 1'000'000> );
    // does not compile
    const std::unique_ptr< std::array<int, 1'000'000> > uptr2 { std::make_unique< std::array<int, 1'000'000> >( { } ) };

    for ( const auto elem : *uptr1 )
    {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I can get it to at least compile by removing the inner braces and doing `std::make_unique< std::array<int, 1'000'000> >(  )`. However I'm not sure what exactly is going on there because `std::array` uses aggregate initialization and I'm not sure how that interacts with `make_unique`.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson Aha! yeah, it compiles by removing the braces. Thanks.

Comment: This piece of code, like almost all uses of `make_unique`, might be a good place to use `auto`, as well...

Comment: Why would you ever want to allocate a `std::array` dynamically?  If you want a dynamic array, use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or `std::vector<T>` instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Well, `std::vector` has a bit of overhead in terms of storage (24 bytes) while `std::array` doesn't have that (except for 8 bytes for the `unique-ptr`). And why should one use a vector when the size of the required array is known at the time of writing the code? vector is suitable for situations when shrinking or extending is needed.  Also speaking of raw arrays (`std::unique_ptr<T[]>`) the [**C++ Core Guidelines**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rsl-arrays) recommends us to avoid using C arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::make_unique< std::array<int, 1'000'000> >( { } )`  does not compile because the `std::make_unique` function template takes an arbitrary number of arguments by forwarding reference, and you can't pass `{}` to a forwarding reference because it has no type.

However, `std::make_unique< std::array<int, 1'000'000> >()` works just fine. It initializes the `std::array` the object in the same manner as the declaration `auto a = std::array<int, 1'000'000>();`: that is, value-initialization. Just like aggregate initialization from `{}`, in the case of this particular type, value-initialization will initialize it to all zeroes.

Comment: So, do you know a way to also initialize the elements of the array with a value (e.g. 5)? Or should I use `std::fill( (*uptr1).begin( ), (*uptr1).end( ), 5 );` after creating the array?

Comment: @digito_evo There is no constructor for `std::array` that initializes all elements to 5, because `std::array` only has defaulted default, copy, and move constructors. `std::fill` is the right tool.

Comment: @digito_evo You could potentially use `integer_sequence` to help you create an array like that pre-20: https://godbolt.org/z/9fjKxqPvn , but `std::fill` has been made  constexpr in c++20, so you can create a helper function with `fill` now: https://godbolt.org/z/vq5Wcc6v5 . Also not sure about your use case, you might consider using `valarray`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Thanks for the suggestion. However, creating huge arrays on the stack is not possible so I would modify your code to return a unique pointer to the created array.